# Unity3D: how to call function in one script from other script that attached to prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have object A and prefab B. On each attached scripts "ScriptA" and "ScriptB". In "ScriptA" i need call function from "ScriptB". I tried this (C# code):

```
public ScriptB MyScript;
MyScript.function();
```

But i cant attach object A to public variable "MyScript", i just see crossed circle icon. What the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a minimum verifiable complete example?  The code you provided tells me nothing about your setup, or the class(structure) of `ScriptB`.

Comment: ScriptB:

`using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScriptB: MonoBehaviour {
 void function()
 {
 //Some code
 }
}`

Comment: We still have no idea how you are try to attach it, is both your "Object A" and "Prefab B" in the scene?  Are you dragging "Script B" from the inspector into the slot? Or are you clicking the little circle to attach it?  Also put your code in your question not as a comment.

Comment: You cant reference a script (monobehaviour) that is on a prefab (prefab means it is in the assets folder, not in the actual scene) from an object that is in the scene. You can only reference a script if it is also on an object in the scene.

Answer (score 2):

> how to call function in one script from other script that attached to
>   prefab?

You can't do this directly because this is a prefab. To access the script attached to a prefab, instantiate the prefab, then use `GetComponent` to get the script.

```
//Assign the prefab from the Editor
public GameObject prefab;
public ScriptB MyScript;

void Start()
{
    //Instantiate prefab 
    GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab);

    //Get script attached to it
    MyScript = obj.GetComponent<ScriptB>();

    //Call the function
    MyScript.function();
}
```

---

If `ScriptB` is already attached to a GameObject in the scene(seeing in the Hierarchy tab) then you don't have to instantiate it. Just Find the GameObject and then use `GetComponent` to get the script attached to it.

```
ScriptB MyScript;

void Start()
{
    //Find the GameObject
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectScriptBIsAttachedTo");

    //Get script attached to it
    MyScript = obj.GetComponent<ScriptB>();

    //Call the function
    MyScript.function();
}
```

Comment: In the latter case, drag and drop would work in the inspector.

Comment: @GunnarB. Yes, it would have

Answer (score -1):

If you use a public gameObject you can refer to the script. Then you can refer to the function in the script.

```
//This would be in script A

public gameObject objectB;

void Start () {
  objectB.functionB();
}
```

Just make sure that your function is a `public void`.

```
//This would be in script B

public void functionB () {
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: `GameObject` does not have a function called `functionB`.  Not to mention `GameObject` is a built-in Unity type.  So to call `functionB` off of a script attached to the specified `GameObject` you would have to call `getComponent<ScriptName>()` on that `GameObject`.

Comment: To call a function from another script, it doesnt need to be a `public void`, just `public`

Comment: I writed in my first post that I know about it, but i cant attach objectB to ScriptA in inspector because I just see crossed circle icon